# Unable to log socket id during disconnection in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, transport

I am trying to log the socket id when a user logs out of a chat room.
Currently the logger is saying 'transport close has left the chatroom' instead of logging the socket id.

I have been able to get it to log 'transport close' or 'undefined' but can't seem to get it to save the socket.id before the connection closes.  What am I doing wrong?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var user_id = socket.id;
    io.emit('broadcast', `--${user_id} has joined the chat room`);
    console.log(`[${user_id}] has joined the chat room`);
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', `[${user_id}] ${msg}`);
    console.log(`[${user_id}] ${msg}`);
});
socket.on('disconnect', function(user_id){
    io.emit('broadcast', `${user_id} has left the chat room`);
    console.log(`${user_id} has left the chat room`);
    })
});
```

Comment: The argument passed to the `disconnect` event is the [reason why the socket got disconnected](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99), not a user id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `socket.id` instead of `user_id`. Your callback `function(user_id)` is incorrect.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
       io.emit('broadcast', socket.id + ' has left the chat room');
       console.log(socket.id + ' has left the chat room');
})
```

Comment: Awesome, I am getting the correct output now.  Thank you!  Not sure why I thought I needed to pass in user_id.. I guess I thought that the ID stored in the variable would persist and get passed into the function.